# Trying to make query with filtering foreign key

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a huge list of sports teams that has their respective league as a foreign key, (NBA, NCAA, MLB, NFL).

In my Django form, I am trying to filter out only the teams with the MLB key but when I do the query with Objects.filter(league='MLB') I get an error that tells me it wants the id number. But when I do Objects.filter(league=3), I don't get an error but the queryset is empty.

Objects.all() returns all the teams from all the leagues. If I run a for loop I can print out all the team's leagues, I just can't seem to search by them.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I appreciate your help.

```py
    Models

    class TeamName(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
        abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
        league = models.ForeignKey(
           'League', null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class League(models.Model):
    leagues = (
        ('MLB', ('MLB')),
        ('NBA', ('NBA')),
        ('NCAAB', ('NCAAB')),
        ('NFL', ('NFL')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=leagues, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
    Forms

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        seasons = Season.objects.filter(name='MLB2021')
        names = [(season.id, season.name) for season in seasons]
        self.fields['season'].choices = names

        team_names = TeamName.objects.filter(league='MLB')
        teams = [(team.id, team.name)for team in team_names]
        self.fields['name'].choices = teams
```

Comment: Can you share leagues model as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field league will have Fk ids, you can filter the name by this:

```
   team_names = TeamName.objects.filter(league__name='MLB')
   teams = [(team.id, team.name)for team in team_names]
   self.fields['name'].choices = teams
```

EDIT:
Reference Doc: [Making queries- Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro)

Comment: Np :) let me know if you still dont get the right queryset !

Comment: Haha i disagree! You always learn something new everytime you get stuck somewhere :) I'll edit the response and add the doc link for this as well

Comment: @RyanThomas mark this answer as accepted if it really worked for you..